# How to run a python file in HTML when button is pressed

Tags: python, html

[image: My Webpage]

When the user clicks the login button, it should run a python file, which is a program that checks user login info.
I'm very new to coding and html so I'm not quite sure if it's possible or not.
*CODE*

```
from flask import Blueprint
auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<p>Login</p>"

#Here is where I'd like to run the python script

@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return "<p>Logout</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run a python file in html using **PHP**.

Write a **PHP** file as "index.php":

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RUN MY PYTHON FILES</title>
<?PHP
echo shell_exec("python test.py 'param1'");
?>
</head>
```

Passing the parameter to python, create a python as "test.py":

```
import sys
input=sys.argv[1]
print(input)
```

Print the parameter passed by PHP.
If your parameter needs to support spaces, try doing this:

```
echo shell_exec("python test.py \"Param 1\"")
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you've done in more detail please? for example, where do I 'import sys'? In the HTML file or PHP file? And do I replace 'test.py' with the python file I want to execute?

Comment: The second part with import sys is the content of the test.py file. Just some example where you can use parameters. Yes, you change the test.py to your file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function and let it do what you want it to do:

```
def your_function():
    # Put whatever it should do here
```

Then, when you want to run the code you wrote in your function, you can call it with. For example, if you want it to run in your login function, do this:

```
@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    your_function()
    return "<p>Login</p>"
```